# understanding epoch time to calculate password ageing in unix

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, epoch

```
my_current_epoch=15684 equivalent time stamp is  Thu, 01 Jan 1970 04:21:24
last_password_reset_epoch_time=15547 equivalent time stamp is Thu, 01 Jan 1970 04:19:07
```

I am not able to understand how difference of these two will give the days since last password reset.

As per my understanding epoch time is denoted in seconds that has elapsed since Jan 1,1970

Can someone please help me understanding this.

Comment: Well those two timestamps are clearly two *minutes* apart. It's extremely unclear what your context is, where those numbers have come from, and what you're actually asking.

Comment: Where are you getting the epoch values from?  The classic Unix timestamp (epoch timestamp) is always in seconds since the epoch.... which your numbers don't not appear to match.

Comment: `# grep 'user' /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{print $3}'
15547`

And found this one-liner from google
`# perl -e 'print int(time/(60*60*24))'
15684#`

Comment: i believe we can calculate the number of days since last password reset using epoch time . Want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man 5 shadow` on a Linux box says:

> The date of the last password change is given as the number of days since Jan 1, 1970. The password may not
>   be changed again until the proper number of days have passed, and must be changed after the maximum number
>   of days. If the minimum number of days required is greater than the maximum number of day allowed, this
>   password may not be changed by the user.

So, you can find out to within 24 hours when a password was changed by multiplying the value from `/etc/shadow` by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day — but you didn't need me to tell you that, did you?).

For the values given (`bc` to the rescue):

- `15684*86400 = 1355097600`
- `15547*86400 = 1343260800`

And:

```
$ timestamp -u 1355097600 1343260800
1355097600 = Mon Dec 10 00:00:00 2012
1343260800 = Thu Jul 26 00:00:00 2012
$
```

Timestamp is my program; modern versions of `date` can handle this too.  The `-u` means 'report in UTC (aka GMT)' rather than in my time zone.

Comment: @Joanthan Leffler .. ok so if the numbers which i hold is days since 1970 then their difference should tell me the number of days since my password was reset. Then i can rely upon them as i was writing a perl script to lookout for accounts whose passwords are expired and print the number of days since last password reset. ( I am using a solaris box)

Comment: Yes; you can rely on the numbers and you can interpret them reliably (now you know the magic ingredient).  The one-liner you found gives you the current number of days since The Epoch; you can compare that with the value in the shadow password file to see how long ago things changed (and when they're next allowed to change, etc).  Read the man page carefully; it tells you an awful lot in very limited space.

Comment: @Joanthan Leffer..ok. First of all i should thank you for you valuable explanation in helping me understand .

`# passwd -s oracle
oracle     PS    07/26/12     0    56`

Also i noticed that the difference between these epoch days gives me a day less than last password reset date.

`# echo "15684-15547" | bc
137`

**Should not the number of days since last password reset is 138 ? as the password was last reset on 07/26/12**

Please help me understand what i am missing here.

Comment: Are we dealing with a 'fence post' problem, aka off-by-one?  15547 is equivalent to 2012-07-26; 15684 is equivalent to 2012-12-10. The difference between those numbers is 137, of course.  I used a wholly separate system that counts days since 1900 (instead of 1970), and calculated the difference between 2012-12-10 and 2012-07-26 as 137 days.  Why do you think 138 is correct?  Alternatively, the problem might be a timezone issue; I'm not sure what the shadow password system records.  (I also checked that 15679 was set for some passwords that I know were changed on 2012-12-05.)

Comment: Lets take today , dec 12 in consideration and talk about how long since password reset
`6days (26th july to 31st of july) + 31 + 30 + 31 +30 + 12 ( my date today is dec 12,2012) = 140`

`so if password was reset on 26th july for the user then should not that be 140 ( which includes the start and end date)`

`where as if i do the math with my epoch values it says 138` . so does it execlude start and end date from the calculation ? Pardon me its more like a fence post :(

Comment: If you change on 26th July, 1 day later is 27th, (28, 29, 30, 31) 5 days in July; 31 August; 30 September; 31 October; 30 November; 12 days in December; 5 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 12 = 139?  Are we in agreement?

Answer (score 2):

> "epoch" value in `/etc/shadow` = 15684 
>  
> the seconds in 24 hours (because normally "epoch" value shows in seconds but for some reason (to make compact view, maybe) in `/etc/shadow` file "epoch" value displays in days, not in *seconds*) = 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400

And by multipliying these two numbers: 15684 (*days*) x 86400 (*seconds per day*); we will get the number 1355097600.

Afterwards, either using [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) by copy/paste the final result, you can get the date, 
*or*
just use `date --date @$(( 15684 * 86400 ))` command in cli